# Not all MIME text showed on mail server

Tags: python, email, mime

I'm using Python email.mime lib to write emails, and I created two MIMEText objects and then attached them to Message as text (not as attachment), and as a result I got the MIME document as follows, as you can see there are two text objects, one is of type plain and the other is of type html, my question is that I can only see the latter text object (here is the html) in some mail clients, while I can see both text objects in some other mail clients (for example, live.com), so what caused this?

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============0542266593=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
FROM: john.smith@NYU.com
TO: john.smith@live.com, john.smith@gmail.com
SUBJECT: =?utf-8?q?A_Greeting_From_Postman?=

--===============0542266593==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

SGkhCkhvdyBhcmUgeW91PwpIZXJlIGlzIHRoZSBsaW5rIHlvdSB3YW50ZWQ6Cmh0dHA6Ly93d3cu
cHl0aG9uLm9yZw==

--===============0542266593==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

ICAgICAgICA8aHRtbD4KICAgICAgICAgIDxoZWFkPjwvaGVhZD4KICAgICAgICAgIDxib2R5Pgog
ICAgICAgICAgICA8cD5IaSE8YnI+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIEhvdyBhcmUgeW91Pzxicj4KICAg
ICAgICAgICAgICAgSGVyZSBpcyB0aGUgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5weXRob24ub3JnIj5s
aW5rPC9hPiB5b3Ugd2FudGVkLgogICAgICAgICAgICA8L3A+CiAgICAgICAgICA8L2JvZHk+CiAg
ICAgICAgPC9odG1sPgogICAgICAgIA==

--===============0542266593==--
```

Comment: Your result is not a well-formed multipart MIME object. In particular, the email headers are missing the 'Content-Type'. How any specific mail client interprets this incorrect input seems unpredictable at best.

Comment: @Robᵩ sorry, I missed the first line when pasting the MIME document, actually the 'Content-Type' was there, now I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified 'multipart/mixed' as the mime type. If you want only one item to be displayed, specify 'multipart/alternative', as so:

```
email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.encoders import encode_base64

# Note: 'alternative' means only display one of the items. 
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Hello"
msg['From'] = 'me@example.com'
msg['To'] = 'you@example.com'

msg.attach(MIMEText('Hello!', 'plain'))
msg.attach(MIMEText('<b>Hello!</b>', 'html'))

# Not required, but you had it in your example, so I kept it.
for i in msg.get_payload():
    encode_base64(i)

print msg.as_string()
```

Comment: I aim to display both items so I used mixed, but my question is that in some mail clients, there's only the last item displayed, it seems there's something to do with the capabilities of the mail server system, what do you think?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your intent. No, it shouldn't have anything to do with the mail server-- it should have everything to do with the mail client.

Comment: So, is there a way that multi-attached MIMEText objects get displayed in every mail clients? since now for some mail clients, only the last MIMEText object get displayed. Though RFC 2046 has mentioned in some cases only the last MIMEText can get displayed, I want to figure out if there's a way that I can get all items displayed, no matter what kind of clients it is?